# Show that $P$ is a partition of the corresponding set $A$ and define the equivalence relation induced by partition $P$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

$A = \mathbb N$ and $ P = \{ \{ m \in \mathbb N: m \ \ \text{is a multiple of} \ \  3\}, \{ m \in \mathbb N: m \ \ \text{is not a multiple of 3}\} \} $.

How can I define the equivalence relation induced by P?

I don't know how to start.

Comment: I don't know if it's what you mean but you can say that $x \sim y$ iff ($3$ divides $x$ and $x-y$) or ($3$ doesn't divides $x$ and $y$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was noted in the comments, you can simply define the equivalence relation by direct reference to its two equivalence classes:

$$m\sim n\text{ iff }(3\mid m\text{ and }3\mid n)\text{ or }(3\not\mid m\text{ and }3\not\mid n)\;.\tag{1}$$

If you want to compress this into something more elegant, notice that $n^2\equiv 0\pmod 3$ iff $n\mid 3$, and $n^2\equiv 1\pmod3$ iff $3\not\mid n$, so that the relation $(1)$ can also be defined by

$$m\sim n\text{ iff }m^2\equiv n^2\pmod 3$$

or, equivalently,

$$m\sim n\text{ iff }3\mid m^2-n^2\;.$$